# vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT") returns null

Tags: c++, vulkan

Im following [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers) tutorial. I am now at the "Testing" part but my Programm always halts with the message "failed to set up debug messenger!".

With debugging I was able to pinpoint the Problem to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT")` returning null.

Full code:

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

const uint32_t WIDTH = 800;
const uint32_t HEIGHT = 600;

const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
        "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};

#ifdef NDEBUG
const bool enableValidationLayers = false;
#else
const bool enableValidationLayers = true;
#endif

VkResult CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT* pDebugMessenger) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDebugMessenger);
    } else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}

void DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        func(instance, debugMessenger, pAllocator);
    }
}

class HelloTriangleApplication {
public:
    void run() {
        initWindow();
        initVulkan();
        mainLoop();
        cleanup();
    }

private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
    VkInstance instance;
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger;

    void initWindow() {
        glfwInit();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    void initVulkan() {
        checkExtension();
        createInstance();
        setupDebugMessenger();
    }

    void populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT& createInfo) {
        createInfo = {};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
        createInfo.messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT
                | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT
                | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT;

        createInfo.messageType = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT
                | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT
                | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT;

        createInfo.pfnUserCallback = debugCallback;
    }

    void setupDebugMessenger() {
        if (!enableValidationLayers) return;

        VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT createInfo;
        populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(createInfo);

        createInfo.pUserData = nullptr; // Optional

        if (CreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, &createInfo, nullptr, &debugMessenger) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to set up debug messenger!");
        }
    }

    void createInstance() {
        if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
        }

        VkApplicationInfo appInfo{};
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

        VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

        auto extensions = getRequiredExtensions();
        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

        uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
        const char** glfwExtensions;

        glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;

        VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugCreateInfo{};
        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
            createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();

            populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(debugCreateInfo);
            createInfo.pNext = (VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT*) &debugCreateInfo;
        } else {
            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

            createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        }

        if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
        }
    }

    void checkExtension() {
        uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

        std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensions(extensionCount);
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, extensions.data());

        std::cout << "available extensions:\n";

        for (const auto& extension : extensions) {
            std::cout << '\t' << extension.extensionName << '\n';
        }
    }

    bool checkValidationLayerSupport() {
        uint32_t layerCount;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

        for (const char* layerName : validationLayers) {
            bool layerFound = false;

            for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers) {
                if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
                    layerFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!layerFound) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    std::vector<const char*> getRequiredExtensions() {
        uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
        const char** glfwExtensions;
        glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

        std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);

        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            extensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);
        }

        return extensions;
    }

    static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
            VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity,
            VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType,
            const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* pCallbackData,
            void* pUserData) {

        const char* severityText = "[UNDEFINED] ";
        if(messageSeverity == VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT) {
            severityText = "[DIAGNOSTIC] ";
        } else if (messageSeverity == VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT) {
            severityText = "[INFO] ";
        } else if (messageSeverity == VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT) {
            severityText = "[WARNING] ";
        } else if (messageSeverity == VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT) {
            severityText = "[ERROR] ";
        }

        std::cerr << severityText << "validation layer: " << pCallbackData->pMessage << std::endl;

        return VK_FALSE;
    }

    void mainLoop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    void cleanup() {
        if (enableValidationLayers) {
            DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, debugMessenger, nullptr);
        }

        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwTerminate();
    }
};

int main() {
    HelloTriangleApplication app;

    try {
        app.run();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Im running Windows 10 with a AMD Radeon RX 5700XT, the newest available driver (AMD Software: Adrenalin Edition Version 2023.0217.1326.1963) and the LunarG vulkan SDK (Version 1.3.239.0).

Ive already looked around the internet and made sure that:

- VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation is avaible in the Vulkan Configurator
- VK_EXT_debug_utils shows up in vulkaninfo
- the Extensions and Validation-Layers are put in createInfo before vkCreateInstance is called
- vkCreateInstance is called before vkGetInstanceProcAddr

  - vkCreateInstance returns "succes" and the instance adress changes
- vkGetInstanceProcAddr is called with the correct instance
- vkDestroyInstance is NOT called before vkGetInstanceProcAddr

However the function still returns null.

Comment: You aren't requesting the `VK_EXT_debug_utils` extension, as you overwrote it with the GLFW required extensions. You'll have to merge the two sets before passing it to vulkan.

Answer (score 0):

Like van dench pointed out I overwrote the result of getRequiredExtensions (which includes the VK_EXT_debug_utils) with the result of glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions.

Removing the override helped (The merging already happens in getRequiredExtensions).
It works with the following createInstance function:

```
void createInstance() {
    if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
    }

    VkApplicationInfo appInfo{};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    auto extensions = getRequiredExtensions();
    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugCreateInfo{};
    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();

        populateDebugMessengerCreateInfo(debugCreateInfo);
        createInfo.pNext = (VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT*) &debugCreateInfo;
    } else {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

        createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    }

    VkResult createResult = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);

    if (createResult != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
    }
}
```